# Global hotkey - Copy own Text into Clipboard C#

Tags: c#, global, clipboard, global-hotkey

Is there any existing class which can insert a predefined text after pressing a predefinded hotkey like ctrl + g? This should work when the application minimized, too.

Best regards,

Edit: Thanks for linking me this thread. Whenever i try to import this. I am getting this error: cannot access static enum member 'Control' in non-static context

Any help here?

Comment: Your question is unclear, where do you want to insert the text? Your form will only receive keypress events when it has focus, to receive other keypress events you would need to register a global hotkey. When it has focus, you just have to set the KeyPress property of the form to true and register the hotkey combination and the action you wish to take

Comment: the text should be inserted like copy paste (ctrl + c and ctrl v) just using a predefined hotkey.

Comment: You should show some context.

Comment: something like test-abd\test.abcd-adcs